# Chart.js | Trouble refreshing line chart with "setInterval"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web, chart.js

Wondering if anyone can help me out please.

I'm having trouble getting a Chart.js LineChart (with AJAX data) to refresh every "X" seconds. I've tried to put the code below in a function inside a setInterval and eventhough it does refresh, it redraws itself in a "zoomed-in" manner...

I want the chart to refresh itself every 10 seconds.

Code:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("ChartRT")',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success:
            function (chartsdata_RT) {
                var aData = chartsdata_RT;
                var aLabels = aData.map(c => c.Period);
                var aDatasets1 = aData.map(c => c.FAILED);
                var aDatasets2 = aData.map(c => c.OTHER);
                var aDatasets3 = aData.map(c => c.DELIVERED);
                var aDatasets4 = aData.map(c => c.PENDING);
                var dataT = {
                    labels: aLabels,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "FAILED",
                            data: aDatasets1,
                            borderColor: '#ff0000',
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)",
                            fill: 'true'
                        },
                        {
                            label: "OTHER",
                            data: aDatasets2,
                            borderColor: '#3366ff',
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(32, 162, 219, 0.3)",
                        },
                        {
                            label: "DELIVERED",
                            data: aDatasets3,
                            borderColor: '#009900',
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 102, 0, 0.3)",
                        },
                        {
                            label: "PENDING",
                            data: aDatasets4,
                            borderColor: '#ff9900',
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 153, 219, 0.3)",
                        }

                    ]
                };

                var ctx = $("#chart_last2hours").get(0).getContext("2d");
                ctx.canvas.height = "50";
                var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: dataT,
                    options: {
                        legend: {
                            display: true,
                            position: 'right',
                            fullWidth: false,
                            labels: {
                                fontColor: '#484848',
                                fontsize: 10,
                                boxWidth: 20,
                                padding: 5,
                                lineWideth: 0
                            }
                        }

                    }

                });
            }



        });
```

Comment: Make sure when you are creating the chart again that you are destroying the old one. If you have it in a div I have found that you have to clear the div or it begins to clutter (at least within SharePoint it did for me). Without deleting the old chart you write "over" the other chart but it will still remember the data points causing weird results when you hover over the chart (it will seizure going back and forth between new data and old data lines).

Answer (score 0):

ended wrapping the above code in a function (drawChartRT). I then:

1) Call the function drawChartRT() to draw the LineChart.

2) Inside a setInterval **remove and add** the canvas and call the function drawChartRT().

```
    drawChartRT();
    setInterval(function () {
        $("canvas#chart_last2hours").remove();
        $("#chartdiv_rt").append('<canvas id="chart_last2hours" height="200"></canvas>');
        var div = document.getElementById("chart_last2hours");
        //console.log(div);
        drawChartRT();
    }, 10000);
```

Works like a charm!

Thanks. José